# What happens when interrupting a zip -erm process?

Tags: zip

What happens if you interrupt following command

```
$ zip -erm foo foo/dirfoo1
```

I realized that time will not permit me to finish. What happens when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> me out of this? Am I left with something that could be continued where it left off? If so, would that be as simple as re-running the command?
Or am I going to find what is not unzipped, and can I run the command for the "leftovers"?

Comment: why don't you try experimenting with it, and then post your results as your answer.

Comment: that's exactly what I tried, 2min into the posting of my Q, but I had not enough "karma" to answer my own within such a short time interval ... zip process is volatile - i.e. crtl/c removes everything created temporarily.

Comment: ^Z should work though

Answer (score 1):

> Am I left with something that could be continued where it left off

No. If you send a an [Interrupt Unix Signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) to `zip` using <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, you'll terminate the `zip` process and when you run it again it will start from the beginning, overwriting anything it already extracted.

If you instead send a *Stop* signal <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>, the `zip` process will be paused, and you can resume it later using the `fg` command.

Note that this will only work if you can maintain the state of your system. That is, if you sleep the system you'll be OK, but if you shutdown, then `zip` will still be killed. Also, it assumes that the file `zip` was working with remains available while it is stopped; that is, if it resides ona  network share which you dismount, sending a SIGSTOP will still not work.